# When is “culture shock" uncountable?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

According to `Oxford Learner's`, `Wiktionary`, and  `Cambridge dictionaries`, `“culture shock"` is both countable and uncountable, but I've never seen or heard the word used in a way which shows it to be uncountable.

Could you please illustrate in which contexts it could be uncountable?

Regards,

Comment: When it's a condition, it's abstract and uncountable; when it's an event (e.g, repeated shocks to the culture) it's countable.

Comment: When have you ever heard it used in a *countable* way? I never have . . . ("I've been affected by two culture shocks"?)

Comment: @Jason Bassford He had never left his village before so arriving in the capital, Manila, was a big culture shock. (Oxford Learner's Dictionary)

Comment: @John Lawler Accurate and convincing answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

See [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/culture-shock) definition:

Culture shock (uncountable noun [oft a noun]):

> Culture shock is a feeling of anxiety, loneliness, and confusion that people sometimes experience when they first arrive in another country.
>
> - *Callum, recently arrived in Glasgow, is jobless, homeless, friendless, and suffering from culture shock.*

Comment: What do you say about the information in the dictionaries I mentioned regarding my question?

Comment: @PaymaanSamimy - they are correct. Culture shock is both countable and uncountable. I added information about the uncountable usage which you appear to be less familiar with.